# Proper way to size a byte array type punning of a struct in C

Tags: c

Suppose I have this definition:

```
struct A {
    union {
        struct {
             T1 f1;
             T2 f2;
             T3 f3;
             ...
        };
        char bytes[...];
};
```

Is there a way, in standard C (or gnu-c++14 where as far as I understand union type punning is allowed to a certain extent) to automatically size the `bytes` array to be as big as the unnamed struct it is `union`ed with?

Comment: Can I have some explanation on comments of why this question has been flagged for closing as "unclear what you are asking"? Which point is not clear?

Comment: A note (the C++ tag having been removed) what it looks like you have in mind is illegal in C++. Only the last union member written can be read without invoking undefined Behavior. That said, it often works with simple structures, but no guarantees are given by the C++ standard.

Comment: @user4581301 as far as I understand gnu extensions to c++ allow this. The codebase I'm using this is actually gnu-c++14. I would be happy to have some solution which uses c++ constructs to get that size, hence the C++ tag. Indeed this definition is valid also in standard c++, only the type punning wouldn't be

Comment: Without extensions, you could use a macro `#define ANON_STRUCT struct { T1 f1; T2 f2; T3 f3; }` and then `...union{ ANON_STRUCT; char bytes[sizeof(ANON_STRUCT)]; }`. (While I guess `ANON_STRUCT` could theoretically be sized differently when standalone and when embedded, I  think it's extremely unlikely.)

Comment: @pqnet even with extensions, just wait til you try this with a `std::string` somewhere in the mix.

Comment: pqnet, "Is there a way, ... to automatically size the bytes array" --> Let us say there is a way `X` and then code uses that to do `Y`. If the way `X` does not exist, yet  `Y` may be achieved by other means.  What is your reason for needing `X`? IOWs, what is `Y`?

Comment: @chux you're right, I should specify that as I'm patching old code the struct public interface should stay as similar as possible as this. Alternative solutions are welcome, extra points are awarded for solution which do not require specific compilers and specific compiler flags, preserve the observable part of the struct (i.e., member names, punning behavior and total size/alignment) compared to writing the correct size manually, and of course better maintainability and robustness against changes such as changing the type and number of members in the anonymous struct

Comment: @pqnet Thanks for the feedback, yet it still misses why is the size needed - how is that size used?  Why not use `char bytes[1];`?

Comment: @chux `bytes[1]` looks smart, but accessing an array out of bound is definitely undefined behaviour. I prefer having a codebase with specific compiler constructs (that would thus fail to compile if ported) than relying on something that could change even with version on the same compiler. I do believe that the compiler for example is allowed to align the array end to the unnamed struct end, such that `bytes[2]` refers to bytes outside of `struct A`

Comment: pqnet So one of the `Y` goals is to access `bytes[]`  (the whole array?). What else - like size computations on `bytes`, alignment test on `bytes`?  OTOH, is [@PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53127480/2410359) good answer meets your goals, we are likely done.

Comment: @chux i want `bytes[]` to be sized the same as the anonymous struct, for type punning (say for example write in the anonymous struct fields, copy the bytes to another `struct A` with a for loop and read the field values back there). PSkocik answer is good, but not satisfying enough to solve my case (the gcc language extension options do not work in c++ mode, and the macro approach might indeed be ABI dependent - we don't really know if it would work properly)

Comment: "copy the bytes to another struct A with a for loop" --> Can be done without a `for()` loop.  `struct A { ...} u1, u2; u1 = u2;` or `memcpy(&u1, &u2, sizeof u1);`.  I still assert that it would be useful to see the use cases, so we can solve them, rather than solve this "size the bytes array to be as big as the unnamed struct" sub-problem.  UV for an interesting problem - yet I wish it was more complete.

Comment: @chux if you relax requirement you end up with a different problem. The scenario I pictured has a large codebase relying on `struct A` to be interface compatible and binary compatible with the union between anonymous struct and byte array depicted above, assume that changing any of the two might require touching many points in the codebase, which makes hard to ensure nothing ends up broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the size of the anonymous struct, it would have to be not anonymous but then within standard C, you couldn't address its members transparently.

```
typedef int T1,T2,T3; //example types
struct name{ //originally anonymous struct given a name
     T1 f1;
     T2 f2;
     T3 f3;
};
struct A{
    union {
        struct name embedded;
        char bytes[sizeof(struct name)];
        //^can size it now that is has a name
    } ;
}u;
```

Under extended C (`-fms-extensions`/`-fplan9-extensions` with gcc) you can do:

```
typedef int T1,T2,T3;
struct name{
     T1 f1;
     T2 f2;
     T3 f3;
};
struct A{
    union {
        struct name; //embed struct name transparently
        char bytes[sizeof(struct name)];
    } ;
}u;
```

but in any case, none of this is necessary as the C standard explicitly allows you to reinterpret any object as a char array without causing any undefined behavior (Simply cast the pointer to the object to `char*` and pretend you're reading a `char` array).

Edit: if you need reinterpreting via a type other than char, you could use a macro as in:

```
typedef int T1,T2,T3;
#define ANON_STRUCT \
    struct { \
         T1 f1; \
         T2 f2; \
         T3 f3; \
    }
struct A{
    union {
        ANON_STRUCT;
        ANON_STRUCT named_anon;
        #if __cplusplus
        char bytes[sizeof(named_anon)];
        #else
        char bytes[sizeof(ANON_STRUCT)];
        #endif
    } ;
}u;
```

but last time I checked you couldn't use unions for reinterpreting in C++ (only in C) -- you had to stick to using the currently active member.

Comment: I am trying to fix out-of-bound array access warnings on a codebase which used `char[1]` there, so the interface of the struct should be the same (hence I need both transparent embedding and the `bytes` name to be preserved. Also, the type used is not necessarily `char`, in fact char was used to simplify the example (and avoid people getting confused with endianness and similar problems) but the type used is actually a fixed size unsigned integer (whose definition is configuration dependent).

Comment: also: does this gcc specific option works with c++ code?

Comment: @pqnet The extensions don't work in C++ mode. The macro approach does, but AFAIK, unions are only usable for type-punning in C, not C++.

Comment: "reinterpret any object as a `char` array without causing any undefined behavior"  citation?  Sure that does not only apply to `unsigned char`?

Comment: @chux http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7 "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: ... -a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object...-a character type."